# URL changed with pushState function is removed when I click to some parts of my website

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, history, pushstate

I'm using a *Javascript*, *Jquery* , *Backbone.js* page. I have all the code in the same file, so I don't want to change between HTML files. I don't use *Backbone.js* routes. I want to change the URL dynamically and I used `history.pushState()` function, and it works correctly. But when I click to some parts of the website, the URL returns to the inital one. I don't know why...

Comment: You should tell us more: which part are you clicking? Have you a fiddle/demo page? Where is your code?

Comment: This is odd behaviour, I've seen pushState having all kinds of issues on mobile browsers' address space when tapping around the page, but never on a desktop. Please post your code, or share a link to a live website where you are testing it

Comment: Screenshots may be handy here. Hard to understand problem without code or visuals.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem!!
My code has a hidden `<a href="#"></a>`. Clicking an anchor with href="#" will move the scroll position to the top. But in my case it causes an unwanted behavior.